# Counting the number of re-transmission for a single UDP packet transmission in IEEE 802.11

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I was working with a client-server project based on UDP and 802.11 as a link and physical layer. There, the client was trying to probe some packets in the wireless channel to gauge channel condition. This function is required to set up the transmission speed and estimate packet drop rate in my client application.

To carry out that function, it is required to measure the number of re-transmissions (topology is client -----ap ------server: where ----- is a wireless channel)that are occurring in IEEE 802.11.

In the transport layer, there won't be any re-transmission, as UDP is used, but if the wireless channel is bad (no acknowledgment from the receiver MAC), the IEEE802.11 Wi-Fi NIC will re-transmit. So far I could access the RSSI from ~/proc/net/wireless, which gives an idea about the received signal strength but not about the wireless channel condition.

Wireless channel condition could be estimated from the number of retransmission. How should I measure the number of re-transmission in IEEE 802.11 layer, Say for 1 packets from application how many re-transmission (from client) in IEEE 802.11 layer?

Is there any process to access the wifi driver and get the number of re-transmission ?

Comment: Guess: If it is possible at all, it depends on the card and the driver (because retransmission may be done by the firmware, or by the driver). Which card (`lspci -nn`/`lsusb`) and driver (`lsmod` etc.) are you using? Next step would be to go through the source code of the driver, and see if there's a way to get at that information.